# Allow specific hosts to access sails js

Tags: security, sails.js

I am building a REST API with sails js and I want to allow only a specific white list of hosts to request it. I know that this can be configured in CORS config file for Browser to Server requests. But in my case, I need it for Server to Server requests. Thanks

Comment: Since you are using HTTP requests, I'm pretty sure there is not difference.

Comment: CORS config doesn't apply for server/server requests. I tested it... it's mentioned in the doc http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/security/cors

Answer (score 1):

CORS of course can't restrict server-server request because it's applied to browser. You must specify it in controller, maybe some kind like using `special key request` or any kind of authentication that only some requester with some secret key are allowed to access.